# How do I carry my variables from a Bash script into a Perl one?

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables, language-support, perl

I have variables in a bash script that I need to be carried over into a perl one. I have the variables $gal and $obsid declared in the bash script, and then I call the new program.

```
gal=UCLA121
obsid=1896
./my_program
```

The beginning of the perl script loads an image with the phrase

```
$ph_im =  "./$gal/img/${obsid}.img";
```

But the variables are NULL in the new program.

Comment: In the first block meant to be in bash?

Comment: Yeah,  those are the temp values. The real values are directory names. The file structure would be data>UCLA121> 1896. So the snippet here is `for i in */*/; do gal=${i%%/*}; obsid=${i#*/}; obsid=${obsid%/}; echo $gal $obsid; done` and the values are input into a text file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Making variables available to child process in shell script can be done either by exporting variables

```
export foo=bar
```

Or by calling program with variables prepended

```
foo=bar ./my_prog.pl
```

In either case you will need to call `ENV` on them inside perl script

```
my $barfoo = $ENV{'foo'};
```

Answer (score 10):

Using  the environment is a cleaner way.

There is [the `-s` switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

```
$ cat vars.pl
#!perl
use feature 'say';
say "foo=$foo";
say "bar=$bar";

$ echo "$foo,$bar"
123,456

$ perl -s ./vars.pl -foo="$foo" -bar="$bar"
foo=123
bar=456
```

Comment: How would I do this if the perl script takes input parameters such as {1 .. 35}?

`perl -s ./myprogram -$gal="$gal" -$obsid="$obsid" 1 35`

This is what I have and it isn't working right.

Comment: Oh, I see it now, you have too many `$`. The shell is expanding the variables on both sides. `-obsid="$obsid"` -- no $ on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 4):

If you are calling it like

```
./myscript.pl 1 35
```

You can use `@ARGV`.  E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

print "ARGV[0]=$ARGV[0]";
print "ARGV[1]=$ARGV[1]";

print Dumper \@ARGV;
```

Example [source](https://perlmaven.com/argv-in-perl).

This is an old example, so it may not be using the latest style.  I don't have a perl compiler set up at the moment, so I can't test the output.

You can use the `Data::Dumper` to help you debug things.

If you are calling it like

```
perl -s ./myprogram -$gal="$gal" -$obsid="$obsid" 1 35
```

Realize that you may get weird results mixing `@ARGV` and named parameters.  You might want to change how you call it to something like

```
perl -s ./myprogram $gal $obsid 1 35
```

or

```
perl -s ./myprogram -gal="$gal" -obsid="$obsid" -first="1" -second="35"
```

Note also that the named parameters are `-gal`, not `-$gal`.  I'm not quite sure what the `$` would do there, but it would tend to do something other than what happens without it.

Remember, `Data::Dumper` can help you debug things if you get confusing results.